# How to handle decimal value in shell scripts

Tags: linux, shell

I want to use decimal values in shell script but it's not working. I am not getting decimal value.
There are few posts which are suggesting to use 'bc' utility of linux. But on my machine 'bc' is not installed and i have no access to install any utility.
Now is it possible to handle decimal values without bc .
Demo code-:

```
calculatePercentage()
   {
    Value1=$1
    Value2=$2
    val=`expr $Value1 / $Value2`
    echo $val
    }

h=`calculatePercentage "150" "200"`
echo $h
```

Output -:

```
1
```

Comment: yes it might duplicate if you look at one part.But my second part is important without bc utility

Comment: do you have `awk`? or `perl`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Below is Program for your convenience**

```
echo $1 $2 | awk '{div=$1/$2; printf"%0.2f\n", div }'
```

Output :- When executed `bash prog.sh 40 23`

> 1.74

Simple one liner program

Comment: Vote if it Helped you

Answer (score 0):

Stretching absurdity:

```
n1=9381
n2=99999
n1pad="$n1"$(printf "%010d" 0)
result=$(expr $n1pad / $n2)
result=$(printf "%010d" $result | sed 's/\(.\{1,10\}\)$/.\1/')
result=$(printf "%f" $result)
```